# Tagging questions - cleaning, washing, sanitizing

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just retagged [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/40/18), changing "clean" to "washing."  I think we should keep the distinction that clothes are washed, equipment is cleaned, and (preemptively) only things that need to be sanitized should be tagged "sanitizing."

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there's a need to split hairs between *washing* and *cleaning*; a new user typing in a search might not recognize the difference. And with sanitizing there's overlap with sterilization. But in keeping the tags organized, we should definitely edit verbs to all be the same tense.

Comment: Hmm. You might be right about washing/cleaning. Perhaps they should be synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

I think your guidelines are great; assuming there are no objections from anyone else, you should fill out the tag wikis.

Another point of discussion: I would love love love if we used consistent verb forms for tags. I think gerunds (-ing) make the most sense for US users, but am curious if non-native English speakers will find that intuitive enough. (But assuming we went with that convention, the "clean" tag should be "cleaning.")

Comment: I was thinking we should solidify the gerund use too, I'll make another post about it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it likely that a user browsing will select a tag associated with equipment cleaning? Is that sufficiently distinguishing that it makes sense?